# Java amplitude processing

Tags: audio, sampling, amplitude, java

I have some code that collects amplitudes from a complex sound like a song. I now want to plot a graph of amplitude vs time, for the graph plotting I use JavaFX. However I get about 9 million amplitude shorts for each channel, so how to I select a few samples to plot (as plotting 9 million points is obviously out of the question)? Do I need to use the sample rate or sample size? Is there a particular way I should go about this?

*Is this post more suited for StackOverflow?*

```
AudioInputStream in = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
AudioInputStream din = null;
 AudioFormat baseFormat = in.getFormat();
  AudioFormat decodedFormat = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED,
  baseFormat.getSampleRate(), //sample rate
  16,                         //sample size (bits)
  baseFormat.getChannels(),   //channels
  baseFormat.getChannels() * 2,//frame size
  baseFormat.getSampleRate(), //frame rate
  false);                     //little-endian
  din = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(decodedFormat, in);
  byte[] temp = new byte[4];

  //....
  //leftDos and rightDos are streams of shorts
  //....

  int i = 0;
  while (din.read(temp, 0, 4) != -1) {
      if (decodedFormat.getChannels() == 2) {
          leftDos.writeShort(temp[1] * 256 + temp[0]);
          rightDos.writeShort(temp[3] * 256 + temp[2]);
          i++;
      }
  }

 //...retrieve shorts...//
 short[] left = new short[(bytes.length / 2)];

 int len = 0;
 try {
     while (1 > 0) {
         left[len] = leftDIS.readShort();
         len++;
     }
 } catch (EOFException e) {
      System.err.println("End of stream");
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways to do this, but I like this way:

```
// very rough pseudocode
step_size = 9000000 / width_of_window;  // 9000000 or however many points
for each pixel in width of window
  figure out what portion of the audio stream this x value corresponds to
  take step_size shorts corresponding to position in audio stream
  find the minimum and maximum values in that portion of the stream
  draw a vertical line at the current x value with position and length corresponding
      to the min and max values you found
```

So basically you're displaying the min and max values of successive portions of the stream in each column of your draw box, or canvas, or whatever you're using.

Comment: `9000000 / width_of_window` seems fairly arbitrary; that would mean on smaller screens I take less samples, but I want to take the same amount of samples but just not 9 million. My question is what should the sample size be?

Comment: @Cobbles: If this is going on Android, then the right number of samples to take *does* depend on the screen size. Anything else will look ugly some of the time (depending on screen size).  The only problem I see with MackTuesday's approach is that there will be aliasing... however this might not be a problem, depending on how accurate you want your display to be.

Comment: I picked 9000000 because that's how many values you were reading. That's what I meant in the comment, "9000000 or however many points". You'd replace that number with however many values you've read. Sorry that wasn't clear.

It sounds like you're trying to smoosh a curve of 9000000 data points into a much smaller pixel area, right?

Comment: @Peter K: Generally aliasing isn't a concern because you're just trying to roughly convey where the signal is loud and where it's soft. I guess if you needed it to be extra pretty you'd massage the graphics a bit, but my approach is a common method.

Comment: @MackTuesday: Understood. As I said, it might not be a problem, depending on the data they are displaying.

Comment: +1: This is the general procedure used by almost every app for drawing waveform "overviews" as they are often called. When I'm doing this, I usually use absolute values and make the graph symmetric, but that's more a matter of taste.

Comment: I might have to change this approach slightly as my question is asking, perhaps not very well, is there a correct way to choose how many magnitude samples to take; I don't want the accuracy of my amplitude to be dependent on screen size! I was just wondering whether I should divide my 9 million by some special value. Just like run length encoding I don't want to chop off relevant amplitudes.

Comment: How could the accuracy of your amplitude *not* be affected by your screen size? The graph would necessarily be less accurate in a 10-pixel canvas than it would be in a 1000-pixel canvas.

Comment: I may have not been specific; I want to know if there is a correct amount of samples of magnitudes to take to optimise the sampling _before_ cutting the amount of samples to place on a graph. As your answer has answered one of my questions I shall accept it but I was hoping to get some signal processing advice rather than cutting the samples by an arbitrary number.